# Postgres - TCP/IP connection refused over reverse proxy

Tags: postgresql, reverse-proxy, psql

Postgres - TCP/IP connection refused over reverse proxy

I am trying to remotely access a postgres DB (called postgres, with the postgres user) on a windows server <FQDN_1>, via a reverse proxy <FQDN_2>, which is configured to forward any incoming TCP connections on 5432 to <FQDN_1> :

I am using:

`psql -h <FQDN_2> -p 5432 -U postgres postgres`

Returns the following error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "<FQDN_2>" (<IP_2>), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

<FQDN_1> is listening on all IPs, and is accepting incoming connections from the IP for <FQDN_2>, and the firewall is open for TCP over 5432.

Does anyone know what could be the problem please? I have not used a reverse proxy for this purpose before and am unsure if this is causing the problem. Many thanks...

Comment: `iptables -L -n`, `netstat -tln4` output? what are you using as reverse proxy? Does it work if you ssh into the proxy, and try connect to the postgres server? selinux enabled/disabled?

Comment: Thanks - netstat -na output is as follows for 5432: 

***  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING ***

I don't have ssh access to the proxy, AFAIK both proxy and destination are windows servers (not linux)

Comment: This is a networking question that would be better suited for a different Stackexchange site. Also, you should show how you created the reverse proxy.